# Ajax Form Submit with attachment

Tags: ajax, phpmailer

I have a Form on my Site thats submitted true ajax. This Form has a field where to attache .pdf files. How when submitting the form though the file is not send with the rest of data.

How can i get this to work?
Here is my ajax code:

```
$('#submit_btn').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/contact.php',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: $('#contactform').serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {

                        console.log(data.type);
                        console.log(data.msg);

                        var nClass = data.type;
                        var nTxt = data.msg;

                        $("#notice").attr('class', 'alert alert-' + nClass).text(nTxt).remove('hidden');
                        //reset fields if success
                        if (nClass != 'danger') {
                            $('#contactform input').val('');
                            $('#contactform textarea').val('');
                        }

                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
```

On the php side i have phpmailer setup and am handling the file so:

```
if(!empty($_FILES['file'])) {
            $_m->addAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['file']['name']); 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        $('#submit_btn').click(function () {
                    var formData = new FormData($('#contactform'));
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: '/contact.php',
                           // dataType: "json",
                            data: formData ,
                      processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                            success: function (data) {

                                console.log(data.type);
                                console.log(data.msg);

                                var nClass = data.type;
                                var nTxt = data.msg;

                                $("#notice").attr('class', 'alert alert-' + nClass).text(nTxt).remove('hidden');
                                //reset fields if success
                                if (nClass != 'danger') {
                                    $('#contactform input').val('');
                                    $('#contactform textarea').val('');
                                }

                            }
                        });
                        return false;
                    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I am getting this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation" ?

Comment: Look at the [send file upload example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps) provided with PHPMailer for how to do this correctly.

Comment: @Nithin Krishnan P: Yes now the form submits but the validation failes because it seems geting the Post data like this: $_POST["name"] doesnt seems to work anymore?

Comment: @ Synchro: the example explaines nothing about submitting the form by ajax!